# How to access bean objects in session __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object

Tags: php, session

I am creating a cart bean object in php and then storing it in session how ever when i tried to access the array of object from the session it always return one bean object only
Here is bean class

```
Class Cart{

private $quanity;
private $amount;

 function getQuantity() {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    function getAmount() {
        return $this->amount;
    }

 function setQuantity($quantity) {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }

    function setAmount($amount) {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }
```

AddToCart.php

```
$c = new cart();
$c->setAmount("500");
$c->setQuantity("10");

if(isset($_SESSION["cartArray"])){

    $ar = $_SESSION["cartArray"];
    $ar[]=$c;
    $_SESSION["cartArray"]=$ar;

}
else{
    $c;
    $_SESSION['cartArray']= [];
    $_SESSION['cartArray'][]=$c;
}
```

orderHandler.php

```
$ar = $_SESSION["cartArray"];


foreach ($ar as $value) {
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($value);
 echo '</pre>';

}
```

it gives me __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
and if try to write the following line in loop

```
$echo $value->getAmount();
```

error:

> Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "cart" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

Comment: You need to ensure that all Classes present in the session are loaded and available before you open the session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it very clear: *"Please ensure that the class definition "cart" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded **before** unserialize() gets called"*.

What it fails to specify is that the function [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) is called behind the scene by the function [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to initialize the `$_SESSION[]` array.

You probably don't use an autoloader but manually include the needed files. If you were using an autoloader for your classes you wouldn't get the error in the first place.

The solution to your problem is quite simple: just make sure you `include 'cart.php';` (the file that declares the `class Cart`) **before** calling `session_start()`.